# How to Snub Voltage Spike Created by Appliance?

Tags: electrical

I have a dehumidifier in my basement that creates a voltage spike when it comes on.  That voltage spike wreaks havoc with a bunch of other devices on the circuit.  Outfitting the other devices with surge suppressors is not practical.  Is there an alternative solution, such as some device I could connect the dehumidifier into so that the voltage spike it creates does not propagate to the rest of the branch circuit?

Comment: Are you sure it's a voltage spike and not a voltage drop?  Can you switch it to another feed?

Comment: For a voltage drop you would need to have something that stored extra power and that is called a capacitor. The following link is not a full answer but provides some insight https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388717/capacitor-for-regulating-ac-line-voltage

Answer (score 2):

**If** it's a spike, a surge suppressor on the dehumidifier should fix it. Surge suppressors are non-directional.

If it's a **drop**, that won't help. A drop could be from a poor connection with high resistance that is more noticeable when the large load of the dehumidifier starting is applied, or it could just be that the circuit is heavily loaded.